# Use of the plural form when listing two objects in succession in technical writing

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I have a rather technical sentence:

> The mean mesiodistal **positioning error** for the posteriors **was**
>   0.09±0.09 mm and 0.05±0.01 mm for the control and experimental groups, respectively.

I feel as though I should be writing 'positioning errors....were' as I am listing two quantities- however, as there really is only one mean (i.e., the number listed), would this really be warranted?

The edit would appear as so:

> The mean mesiodistal **positioning errors** for the posteriors **were**
>   0.09±0.09 mm and 0.05±0.01 mm for the control and experimental groups, respectively.

Comment: Is there two "mean" or one ?

Comment: Well, for the control group, there would be one mean i.e., 0.09mm, and for the experimental group, there would be one more mean, i.e., 0.05

Comment: There are limits to how much spilled grammar you can mop up with the word *respectively*. And it helps if it is closer to the action. I'd rearrange the sentence to read "The mean mesiodistal positioning errors for the control and experimental groups' posteriors were 0.09±0.09 mm and 0.05±0.01 mm, respectively." Or "The mean mesiodistal positioning error for each of the control and experimental groups' posteriors was 0.09±0.09 mm and 0.05±0.01 mm, respectively."

Comment: I am very tempted to use that expression; however, my editor absolutely hates the use of possessive apostrophes- despite the fact that there is nothing wrong with it. I have to work around it.

Comment: You should try to find a way to remove the prepositional phrases from the measurement and attach them to the thing being measured. I think this will solve your problems

Comment: The question is, how many "mean mesiodistal positioning errors" can the posteriors have? If the answer is "more than one," I don't see any reason to avoid "errors" in your sentence. And if "respectively" is giving you trouble, you can reword as "The mean mesiodistal positioning errors for the posteriors were 0.09±0.09 mm for the control group and 0.05±0.01 mm for the experimental group." In fact, I'd run the singular wording the same way: "The mean mesiodistal positioning error for the posteriors was 0.09±0.09 mm for the control group and 0.05±0.01 mm for the experimental group."

Answer (score 2):

Leaving the posteriors and their measurements to one side for the moment, your question is basically asking what the grammatical number should be when using the word *respectively*.

The following dictionary entry is illustrative, particularly for its examples (emphasis in the examples, mine):

> **Respectively** *adverb*
>   Separately or individually and in the order already mentioned (used when enumerating two or more items or facts that refer back to a previous statement):
>
> - *they received **sentences** of one year and eight months respectively*
> - *These **positions** are frequently referred to respectively as objectivism and constructionism.*
>
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/respectively)

As the examples illustrate, the nouns in question should be plural. This is even clearer if we replace *respectively* with approximations like *in that order* - e.g. "they received sentences of one year and eight months in that order". There were multiple *sentences*, so it's written in the plural.

Returning to your example, then, since you are describing multiple errors, you should use "... errors ... were".

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the phrase "mesiodistal positioning".

> The mean error for the posteriors was [...]

Since mean is an aggregate, there is nothing wrong with this ordinarily. Presumably, there is only one mean error for *n* number of posteriors.

However, because you performed the test for two groups, you *do* have two mean errors--one for the test group and one for the control group. Therefore it would be correct to use the plural "errors", though I very much doubt anyone would criticize you either way.

Comment: I have decided to rearrange another sentence with the same issue slightly:

The mean angulation error was 1.53±1.57° for the control group and 1.52±1.37° for the experimental group.

In this case, would the use of the singular be warranted as the verb is much closer to the noun?

Comment: Placement of the verb to the noun doesn't really matter at all. Instead, you need to consider how many errors there are. In this case, that will depend on whether you're using the term "mean angulation error" to describe a type of error or an instance of an error. Both contexts could be considered correct for this usage, so don't stress over which you pick. If you decide that it's a type of error, of course there is only one type, so you would use the singular. If you decide that its a reference to the two instances of that kind of error, you may use the plural, since there are two instances.

Comment: There is a way to rewrite this sentence without fussing over singular or plural, too. Example: "For the control group, the mean angulation error was 1.53±1.57°, while for the experimental group, it was 1.52±1.37°." In place of the pronoun "it", you could also restate the antecedent instead, as "For the control group, the mean angulation error was 1.53±1.57°, while for the experimental group, the mean degree of error was 1.52±1.37°."